# Emacs : how to load file content in scratch screen

Tags: debugging, emacs, org-mode

### I would like to load "~/todo.org" file content in *scratch* buffer at startup.

I have tried:

```
(setq initial-buffer-choice "~/todo.org")
```

But it opens the file in a new buffer (not *scratch*).

I have also tried:

```
(setq initial-scratch-message "~/todo.org")
```

But it prints the file path in the *scratch* buffer and i would like it's content.

### I also would like to change the mode of the *scratch* buffer to org-mode.

I have tried:

```
(setq initial-major-mode org-mode)
```

But i have an initialisation error

> Symbol's value as variable is void: org-mode

Comment: The splash buffer is not affected by the `initial-major-mode`.  Type:  `M-x describe-variable RET initial-major-mode RET` to learn more about it.  Put a single quote in front of `org-mode`.  You may also want to `(require 'org)` before doing so.  I'm not sure when that library loads and it may depend on the version of Emacs you are using.

Comment: You may also wish to read about `M-x describe-function RET insert-file-contents RET` and `M-x describe-function RET with-current-buffer RET`.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to insert the todo.org file contents into `*scratch*`, as opposed to opening and displaying todo.org itself? Also, is it the *splash* buffer or the *scratch* buffer that you wish to be in `org-mode` (the latter would at least tie in with your other request, but you've written the former, and that makes no sense to me *at all*). This sounds like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378). What problem are you ultimately trying to solve?

Comment: It is the scratch buffer (keyboard - chair bug fixed :) ). I would like to load the file content in this buffer so i can edit the file as "read only but editable".

Comment: "Read-only but editable" is a contradiction. Do you mean that you want a buffer that is not associated with a file? That is, a buffer that is not associated with `~/todo.org` e.g. so you cannot accidentally overwrite it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i'll go for this:

```
(condition-case err
  (when (get-buffer "*scratch*")
    (with-current-buffer "*scratch*"
      (erase-buffer)
      (insert-file-contents "~/todo.org")
      (org-mode)
    )
  )
(error (message "%s" error-message-string err)))
```

Comment: Your code is incorrect.  `setq` is used to set the value of a variable.  If you check the value of your variable after Emacs loads, you will see it is wrong -- `M-x describe-variable RET initial-scratch-message RET`  What is happening is that you just happen to be visiting the `*scratch*` buffer when Emacs evaluates `(insert-file-contents "~/todo.org")` and as luck would have it, your file gets inserted into the `*scratch*` buffer.  Have a look at line 2480 to 2485 to see how `(with-curent-buffer "*scratch*" . . .` is used:  https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/startup.el

Comment: I don't understand, it does the job.Have you a cleanest way to do it ?

Comment: Your code appears to "do[] the job" *by accident* because the `*scratch*` buffer *coincidentally* is the set buffer at the precise moment that your code is called during startup.  If your code were called at a different place in the startup process, the result would be that your `todo.org` file contents would be inserted in a *different* buffer or you would receive an error message if the set buffer is `read-only`.  Here is an example of what you can use instead:  `(when (get-buffer "*scratch*") (with-current-buffer "*scratch*" (erase-buffer) (insert-file-contents "~/todo.org") (org-mode)))`

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm sure we simply came up with similar solutions independently. My apologies.

Comment: So do I. It was a synchronisation problem, next time we should use locks :)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve the desired effect with a little bit of Lisp code that you put in your [init file](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Init-File.html):

```lisp
(condition-case err
    (with-current-buffer "*scratch*"
      (let ((min (point-min))
            (max (point-max))
        (goto-char max)
        (insert-file-contents "~/todo.org")
        (delete-region min max)
        (org-mode)))
  (error (message "%s" error-message-string err)))
```

But as @phils pointed out in a comment to your question, the `*scratch*` buffer might not be the best buffer to use for this functionality. Thus, I suggest to consider the following alternative:

```
(condition-case err
    (let ((buffer (get-buffer-create "*todo*")))
      (with-current-buffer buffer
        (insert-file-contents "~/todo.org")
        (org-mode))
      (setq initial-buffer-choice buffer))
  (error (message "%s" error-message-string err)))
```

By using this version, you leave the `*scratch*` buffer alone. Your `.org` file will be inserted in a separate buffer by the name of `*todo*`. This buffer is not associated with your `~/todo.org` file, so when you first try save it, you will have to specify a file name.

Comment: The doc-strings for `beginning-of-buffer` and `end-of-buffer` suggest that those functions are intended for interactive use; and, to use `(goto-char (point-min))` and `(goto-char (point-max))` when writing your own functions.

Comment: @lawlist Thanks for that!